# convert H:MM:SS to iso

Tags: python, python-3.x, timedelta

so i am taking the difference between two times (2022-07-20 23:10:00.990000) and 2022-07-20 23:10:02.100000. that gives me back 0:00:01.110000. i want that to transform to HH:MM:SS without the microseconds. the easiest way to take off microseconds is to do "avg_inqueue_time = str(avg_inqueue_time).split(".")[0]" that will give me 0:00:01. then i try to do avg_inqueue_time_transformed = datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S', avg_inqueue_time) but gives an error ValueError: time data '%H:%M:%S' does not match format '0:02:07'.

any ideas how to transform that?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it would be better if you would create minimal working code (with example data) which makes this problem - this way we could see if you use it in correct way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a fast approach is to take a different time delta object where you only pick the seconds.

```python
import datetime

time_1 = datetime.datetime(2022,7,20,23,10,00,990000)
time_2 = datetime.datetime(2022,7,20,23,10,2,100000)
timediff=(time_2-time_1)
timediff_wo_microseconds = datetime.timedelta(days=timediff.days, seconds=timediff.seconds)
print(timediff_wo_microseconds)
```

Comment: created the below function

def time_converter_to_HHMMSS(tm):
    time=tm[:].split(":")
    hours=int(time[0])
    minutes=int(time[1])
    seconds = int(time[2])
    
    if hours<10: 
        hours='0'+str(hours) 
    else: 
        hours=str(hours)
    if minutes<10: 
        minutes='0'+str(minutes)
    else: 
        minutes=str(minutes)
    if seconds<10: 
        seconds='0'+str(seconds)
    else: 
        seconds=str(seconds)
    iso_time = str(hours)+':'+str(minutes)+ ":"+str(seconds)
    return iso_time